# Which F# type names and declaration syntax are considered idiomatic?

Tags: f#

F# has multiple ways to declare the same types. This is likely because of the dual lineage of F# as both a member of the ML family and a .NET language. I haven't been able to find any guidance on which style is more idiomatic.

Specifically, I want to know:

- Which is more idiomatic for 64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers in F#, `float` or `double`?
- Which is a more idiomatic way in F# to declare an array type:

  - `int[]`
  - `int array`
  - `array<int>`

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/basic-types
- https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-types#syntax-for-types

Context: I'm working on some API documentation that is explaining how data in a data store maps to .NET types, along with how those types are typically declared in both C# and F#.

Comment: Based on the types displayed in the interactive mode, It appears that float is indeed the default real type of F# that corresponds to a 64-bits floating-point number (i.e. a double). For arrays, it displays int [] while for a list of integers, it displays int list.

Comment: I’ve found that fsi will use int[] when you declare it as such, and int array if you declare it as array<int> or int array

Comment: To the folks who’ve voted to close because this is opinion-based: Yes, things that belong in language style guides are generally a matter of opinion. That doesn’t mean there can’t be authoritative opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

For doubles, it's pretty much always `float`. Unless you deal with both singles and doubles and need to ensure clarity I guess.

For generic types, the usual syntax I use and see people use is:

- `int option`
- `int list`
- `int[]`
- For all other types, including F#-specific ones like `Async`, `Set`, and `Map`, angle bracket syntax is used.

The only type that I feel has a significant split is `seq` (an alias for `IEnumerable`): I'd say the majority of people use `seq<int>` but a significant number of people write `int seq`. Either way, you should definitely use `seq` and not `IEnumerable`. Similarly, you should use the alias `ResizeArray` for `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Answer (score 1):

The [F# Core Library reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/fsharp-core-library-reference), which seems like a good example to follow, seems to prefer `float`, `int[]` and `seq<int>`.